# Siema Ca indicator

Tags: javascript, zepto, siema

I'm using the [Siema carousel](https://github.com/pawelgrzybek/siema) on my site with Zepto. I'd like to be able to indicate what slide the user is currently on. How do I do this if there is only an onChange event available?

HTML

```
<section class="images">
   <img/>
   <img/>
</section>

<section class="indicators">
   <span class="active"></span>
   <span></span>
</section>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  new Siema({
    selector: '.images',
    onChange: () => {
      console.log("swiped");
      // change active indicator?
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: Look under the API section of [Siema carousel](https://github.com/pawelgrzybek/siema) for current slide. This should have an example of the behavior you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I can help (I'm the author of Siema).

```
// extend a Siema class and add addDots() & updateDots() methods
const mySiemaWithDots = new SiemaWithDots({

  // on init trigger method created above
  onInit: function(){
    this.addDots();
    this.updateDots();
  },

  // on change trigger method created above
  onChange: function(){
    this.updateDots()
  },

});
```

https://codepen.io/pawelgrzybek/pen/boQQWy

Have a lovely day